# Hide all pages except one from specific user in WordPress backend

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to hide all pages except one specific from an user (ID=14). This is what I got so far with the help of this post »https://www.johnparris.com/how-to-hide-pages-in-the-wordpress-admin/«:

```
function jp_exclude_pages_from_user($query) {

  if ( ! is_admin() )
    return $query;

  global $pagenow, $post_type;

  if ( !$current_user->14  && $pagenow == 'edit.php' && $post_type == 'page' )
    $query->query_vars['post__in'] = array( '10' ); // Enter your page IDs here


}
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'jp_exclude_pages_from_user' );
```

Result is that my site stops working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an issue with your code. You are fetching user id outside the function. In that case the code should be as below:

```
    function jp_exclude_pages_from_admin($query) {

        if ( ! is_admin() )
            return $query;

        global $pagenow, $post_type;
        $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();

        if ( $current_user_id == 'youruserid' && $pagenow == 'edit.php' && $post_type == 'page' )
            $query->query_vars['post__not_in'] = array( 'yourpageid' ); // Enter your page IDs here

    }
    add_filter( 'parse_query', 'jp_exclude_pages_from_admin' );
```

In the above section you forgot to put $current_user_id that's why it got suspended. Hopefully this code will work. Let me know if it works or not. I've tested it out & it works perfectly on my end

Comment: Thank your Adnan! Works like a charm. I've changend ['post__not_in'] to ['post__in'] to only show the specific page to the user.

Comment: Glad to hear that works. Please upvote the answer if possible & works :)